# Which rating variable is affecting the main rating?

Tags: correlation, importance, rating

I have 3 types of rating, the restaurant rating (main rating), food rating, and service rating. Each of these ratings go from 0 to 2.

I would like to know if it's possible to tell if a restaurant is getting a better/worse rating because of the Food or because of its Service. For example, a restaurant gets a rating of 2 and then Food:2 and Service:1. This tells me that the Food is more important than the Service.

How should I proceed to evaluate this with many examples?

[image]

Is it possible to tell that the Overall Rating is more affected by the Service Rating or the Food Rating?

Comment: can you give a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @NathanMcCoy I'm sorry, I'm not sure how can I provide you that, I just added a table with more examples.

Comment: I believe you can use pearsons correlation to determine which column is more correlated with the overall rating.

Comment: I think that works @NathanMcCoy, thank you very much

Comment: You wouldn't want to use Pearson's correlation for this. These are ordinal variables, and the food & service ratings are likely to be correlated, so you want to use a model that includes both (simultaneously controlling for each).

Answer (score 2):

This is a situation commonly encountered with satisfaction surveys.

A practical solution is to use a [dominance analysis](http://psycnet.apa.org/record/2003-06499-004) implemented in [R](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/relaimpo/index.html), [SAS](http://people.uwm.edu/azen/damacros/), and [Stata](https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s457629.html).

The very similar [Relative weights analysis](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/1094428104266017) can also be [implemented](http://relativeimportance.davidson.edu/).

If it's important to address the ordered-categorical nature of the indicators, that could be [addressed too](http://journals.sagepub.com/doi/abs/10.1177/1094428114544509).

Basically, use service and food (and any others) in a dominance or RWA analysis predicting overall satisfaction.  These methods implement a reasonable method to disentangle the relationship between predictors as was noted as an important to do by @gung (about which I agree).